# Radon Transform of Gaussian function

Tags: gaussian-integral, integral-transforms, radon-transform

I am trying to find the radon transform of the gaussian function
$$f(x,y) = e^{-(x^2 + y^2)}$$

Now, I am using the formula for radon transform as
$$
[\mathcal{R}f]{(\rho, \theta)} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y) \delta(x \cos(\theta) + y \sin(\theta) - \rho) dx dy
$$

When I am solving it, I am replacing $y = (\rho - x \cos \theta)/\sin \theta$ and this boils down the main integral to a single gaussian integral but my final answer results to what is expected but with a $|\sin \theta|$ multiplied with it.

How do i prove analytically that it is equal to $\sqrt{\pi} e^{-\rho^2}$? Can someone help me with the calculations?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Some hints: (1) $\mathcal{R} f(\rho,\theta)$ is just the integral of $f$ along a line specificed by $\rho$ and $\theta$, (2) as $f$ is rotationally symmetric, $\mathcal{R} f$ does not depend on $\theta$, (3) the integral of interest is then $\int_\mathbb{R} f(x,\rho) dx$ and you can evaluate it (if you know the integral of a 1D Gaussian)

Comment: @JanBohr I have been trying to solve it for the general values of $\rho$ and $\theta$, and I am aware of the circular symmetry of gaussian and the intergal of the 1D-Gaussian.

However, when I am solving it, I am replacing $y = (\rho - x \cos \theta)/\sin \theta$ and my final answer results to what is expected but with a $|\sin \theta|$ multiplied with it.

Comment: It will be easier to help you, if you state precisely what you do (line by line) and where you encounter problems. My first suggestion is to get rid of this $\delta$-distribution and write down an expression for $\mathcal{R} f$ as a simple line integral. From there it is easier to reason geometrically (rather than purely formally by making substitutions).

Comment: I guess it helps that you mention a geometrical reasoning for this. I have been trying to get an analytical proof, but just by considering $\theta$ to be not effecting the final sinogram helps in this case. Thank you so much!